# How do I find value of a and b in this matrix question?

Tags: matrices, determinant

This is a question from a homework sheet my teacher gave.
[image: question]

I already did alternate a. Alternate b is quite confusing! It asks to find the value for a and b.

I don't really know what to do but here's what I did:

***aP*** + ***bQ*** = ***S***

 I then divided P and Q on both sides: ***aP/P*** + ***bQ/Q*** = ***S/PQ*** 
I'm left with ***a*** + ***b*** = ***S/PQ***

 Inverse matrix rule: ***S(P^-1)(Q^-1)***

 So, ***a*** + ***b*** = ***S(P^-1)(Q^-1)*** 

 I stopped there.

Comment: aP + bQ = S
I then divided P and Q on both sides: first of all, it it was numbers, you should get aP/(PQ) + bQ/(PQ) = S/PQ, but, worse you CANNOT divide by a matrix

Answer (score 2):

HINT.- Part (a) are simple exercises of matrix multiplication you have to learn.

Part (b), because of the multiplication of a matrix by a scalar, can be possible if and only if there is compatibility of the four following equations:

$$2a+b=1\\1\cdot a+0\cdot b=-2\\3a+0\cdot b=-6\\a+b=3$$ You can verify whitout difficulty that it is in fact compatible.

Comment: Can I solve for a and b simultaneously?

Comment: You have at first sight two compatible equations giving the value of one unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Since matrices $P,Q,S$ are given, $a P + b Q = S$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 a + b & a\\ 3 a & a + b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2\\ -6 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

which gives us a system of $4$ linear equations in $a,b$.

Comment: That looks hairy

Comment: The overdeterminacy is not what we should remember of this system: the main thing is that these equations are compatible and have a unique solution $a=-2, b=5.$

Comment: @JeanMarie Realizing that the system has a unique solution is the OP's job.

Comment: @AugieJavax98 It's so hairy that the system can be solved by visual inspection.

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo I understand. I just wanted to say that this adjective "overdetermined" that probably Augie... doesn't understand... may be misleading for a low level learner, because it is usually used when there will be no solution...

Comment: @JeanMarie I removed the "overdetermined" part. What I meant was that one has a linear system of the form $A x = b$ where $A$ is a "thin" matrix (i.e., more rows than columns). However, when the rows are linearly dependent and the solution set is $0$-dimensional, then there's not much "overdeterminacy" there.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I just started learning about matrices a few weeks ago and I'm finding it quite tricky. I guess I just have to practice more.

Comment: @AugieJavax98 Look at the entries off the main diagonal. We have $a = -2$ and $3 a = -6$. The solution is obviously $a = -2$. Now use the entries on the main diagonal to obtain the value of $b$.